# SVG xlink:href not loading on pages with variables in URL

Tags: html, svg

On every page of my site, I have included to code for an SVG that contains a bunch of icons that I use throughout the site, and when needed I call `<svg><use xlink:href="#svg-icon" /></svg>` to display it. Everything works great on that front, but once I reach a page that has a URL containing a variable (ex: `index.php?page=1`), suddenly none of the SVGs work anymore.

Comment: Do you have a <base> tag in your code? Does changing the URL change the base tag?

Comment: I do have a <base> tag, but the `?page=1` does not affect it.

Answer (score -2):

Possible that parameter triggering some changes in HTML code with errors.

Comment: Debug console doesn't register anything, and I checked to make sure that the source SVG and the `<use />` weren't affected by the `?page=1`